# angular js animate to scroll to top of viewport

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and trying to do something that is already working in Jquery. I do not want to use jquery and angular together and wanted just code it in angular and need some help using this in a directive.

```
// Calculate the current scroll position...
    scrTop = (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset);

    newTop = $elemt.offset().top - 20;
    //$elemt: an Object representing a jQuery selected page element.
    diff = newTop - scrTop;

    if (Math.abs(diff) > 20) {
        newScrTop = scrTop + diff;
        //where NAV_HEIGHT of div id corresponding to the element in the top navigation
        if (diff < 0) newScrTop -= NAV_HEIGHT;
        if (newScrTop < 0) newScrTop = 20;
        jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: newScrTop + 'px'}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is based on a lightweight version of jQuery (jqLite)
thus you can simply use your code in angular even if you remove your explicit jQuery import from your page

Comment: I am using a directive and wanted to use the code in the directive.

Comment: Oh i see, well then when you want the code to trigger ? on a click ?
You can simply create an angular directive, put the code inside of the link function and use the directive on your DOM elements afterwards. The code itself is angular-compatible

Comment: I get error for the offset. Says .offset is not a function trying                        var $el   = element[0];            var elScrollTopOriginal = $($el).offset().top - 10

Comment: what is element[0] ? normally if you do $(el).offset it should work